# Python 2 - printing raw input into an array, formatting output

Tags: python-2.7

I'd like to take raw input from a user and then re-arranging the output in a different order. I have the code working, but the output has single quotes around each number. Here is the really simple code:

```
    CodeNumber=(raw_input("Please enter 4 digit number: "))

    print "Code_A: %r%r%r" %(CodeNumber[3], CodeNumber[1], CodeNumber[0])
    print "Code_B: %r%r%r" %(CodeNumber[2], CodeNumber[3], CodeNumber[1])
```

The output I get is:

```
   Please enter 4 digit number: 1234
   Code_A: '4''2''1'
   Code_B: '3''4''2'
```

How do I remove the single quotation marks so I get 421 instead of '4''2''1'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one way to do this is to use int() on element indices of CodeNumber to turn the strings into numbers.

This is your edited code (by me, hob!)

```
CodeNumber=(raw_input("Please enter 4 digit number: "))
print "Code_A: %r%r%r" %(int(CodeNumber[3]), int(CodeNumber[1]), int(CodeNumber[0]))
print "Code_A: %r%r%r" %(int(CodeNumber[2]), int(CodeNumber[3]), int(CodeNumber[1]))
```

Output:

```
Please enter 4 digit number: 1234
Code_A: 421
Code_B: 342
```

Running time = O(n)

Comment: I'm sorry, I know we're not supposed to say "thanks" or anything, but I can't help it. I just knew it was going to be something small I was missing. Thank you so much for your help! And I love that you added the running time! Thank you!!!!!